# How can conditional rendering based on privilege

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not able to show / hide the `delete` icon based on following code. If the `privilege == "ADMIN"` then display the delete icon, but if the privilege == "PLAYER" then hide it.

Then below code is not working,

```
const [deleteIcon, setDeleteIcon] = useState({ show: false});


 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
       const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/players');
       setPlayerList(res.data.players);
       setSearchResults(res.data.players);
       const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');
       console.log("Privilege logging in Front End:"+privilege);
       showDeleteIcon(privilege);
      } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
     }
   }
  fetchData();
 }, []);


  const showDeleteIcon = (privilege) =>{
    if(privilege === "ADMIN"){
      setDeleteIcon({show:true})
    }else{
      setDeleteIcon({show:false})
    }
  }

   { deleteIcon &&(
    <span className="deletePlayerIcon">
       <img src="images/deleteIcon.png"/>
    </span>
    )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your conditional rendering statement, you will need to go 1 level deeper into the `deleteIcon` state object:

```
{deleteIcon.show && (
  <span className="deletePlayerIcon">
   <img src="images/deleteIcon.png"/>
  </span>
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that you're storing an object into deleteIcon. So you have to do like this

```
   { deleteIcon.show &&(
    <span className="deletePlayerIcon">
       <img src="images/deleteIcon.png"/>
    </span>
    )}
```

Comment: Is this help you then please do it as marked so we can close this question.